# Hibernate : Not allowing cascaded delete because of Foreign key violations

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql, spring-mvc

I am working on a Spring-MVC application in which I am trying to delete an entity, which has one-to-many relationships with 3 other entities. I have marked the entities to be deleted on Cascade, but it is not working. I am getting an error of foreign key violation..

Notes Entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="groupnotes")
public class GroupNotes {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "mnotedata",fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    private Set<GroupAttachments> mattachments = new HashSet<>();

    public Set<GroupAttachments> getMattachments() {
        return this.mattachments;
    }

    public void setMattachments(Set<GroupAttachments> mattachments) {

        this.mattachments = mattachments;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "mhistory",fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    private Set<GroupNoteHistory> groupNoteHistorySet = new HashSet<>();

    public Set<GroupNoteHistory> getGroupNoteHistorySet(){
        return this.groupNoteHistorySet;
    }

    public void setGroupNoteHistorySet(Set<GroupNoteHistory> groupNoteHistorySet){
        this.groupNoteHistorySet = groupNoteHistorySet;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "unreadNotes",fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    private Set<UnreadNotes> unreadNotesSet = new HashSet<>();

    public Set<UnreadNotes> getUnreadNotesSet(){
        return this.unreadNotesSet;
    }

    public void setUnreadNotesSet(Set<UnreadNotes> unreadNotesSet){
        this.unreadNotesSet = unreadNotesSet;
    }
}
```

Entity GroupAttachments :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "groupattachments")
public class GroupAttachments {
@ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "mnoteid")
    @OnDelete(action = org.hibernate.annotations.OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private GroupNotes mnotedata;

    public void setMnotedata(GroupNotes mnotedata){this.mnotedata=mnotedata;}

    public GroupNotes getMnotedata(){return mnotedata;}
}
```

But when I execute the code below :

```
 @Override
    public boolean deleteAllNotesForSection(int msectionid) {
        session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        org.hibernate.Query query = session.createQuery("from GroupNotes as " +
                "n where n.ownednotes.msectionid=:msectionid");
        query.setParameter("msectionid",msectionid);
        List<GroupNotes> groupNotesList = query.list();
        for(GroupNotes groupNotes : groupNotesList){
            groupNotes.getGroupNoteHistorySet().clear();
            groupNotes.getMattachments().clear();
            groupNotes.getUnreadNotesSet().clear();
            session.flush();
        }

        org.hibernate.Query query1 = session.createQuery("delete from GroupNotes as " +
                "n where n.ownednotes.msectionid=:msectionid");
        query1.setParameter("msectionid",msectionid);
        query1.executeUpdate();
        session.flush();
        return true;
    }
```

I get the following error when I execute the above code :

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement] with root cause
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: update or delete on table "groupnotes" violates foreign key constraint "groupnotes_groupnotehistory_fk" on table "groupnotehistory"
  Detail: Key (mnoteid)=(5455) is still referenced from table "groupnotehistory".
```

Isn't the first query which clears all the set, should clear from the database the history and all. And ideally there shouldn't be a problem, as it is cascade delete. I also tried retrieving the List using query1.list and deleting in a for-loop, that also didn't work. I don't understand how to remedy this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: See the following:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5682355/hibernate-cascading-delete-not-working-as-expected

Comment: I added Cascade.ALL, then it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Several things are wrong here. First, calling `clear()` handles just one side of bidirectional relation. You need to visit every child and set its reference to `GroupNote` to null. The way you wrote it, the database will stay the same after flush, no entities will be deleted.

Second, calling `delete` in HQL bypasses `cascade` options. So even without the first problem, no related entities will be deleted this way, leading to the exception you are seeing.

Comment: But when I am just calling a note delete function, for a note which has NoteHistory and Attachment, then it works fine, only when I want to delete a bunch of notes together, then I am getting an error. That is why I cannot understand, as there is a DAO method where I am doing getById from database and using session.delete(note_object_name) and session.flush(), then it works.